# Restarting GNOME Shell takes a long time and throws an error

Tags: command-line, 18.04, gnome-shell, gnome-shell-extension

Every time I restart GNOME Shell with <kbd>ALT</kbd>+<kbd>F2</kbd> > `r` it takes about 1.5min and displays an error when its done. But it restarts successfully somehow.
I am on Ubuntu 18.04 LTS, everything up to date.

Comment: If possible, can you please a picture of error?

Comment: What does the error say? You probably have a bad GNOME extension. Edit your question and show me `ls -al ~/.local/share/gnome-shell/extensions`. Go to https://extensions.gnome.org/local/ and temporarily disable ALL extensions, then try to restart GNOME Shell. It'll probably restart quickly. Report back. Start comments to me with @heynnema or I'll surely miss them.

Comment: It says that Gnome has had a problem, nothing else. In the details it gives the path to gnome shell binary...

Comment: Disabled all extsnsions besides ubuntu dock, still takes ages to restart